# Recreate table-like graphics

Tags: tables

I'd like to [recreate a calculation](http://www.computerhistory.org/babbage/howitworks/img/4-1.jpg) similar to:

[image]

I tried using a table with blind cells and `\swarrow`, but the arrows are to steep. A second try was using `xymatrix`, but the distances between the rows were to large.

Do you have a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not shown any code to help get started, my first thought was to use a TikZ `matrix of math nodes`. Matrices are further discussed starting on page 654 of the v3.0.0 manual. With this construct, you can draw lines between the cells very easily. Hope the following can help you get started!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (diff) [matrix of math nodes]{
        & & \text{1st} & \text{2nd} \\
        x & F(x) & \text{difference} & \text{difference} \\
        1 & 5 & & \\
          &   & 3 & \\
        2 & 8 & & 2 \\
          &   & 5 & \\
        3 & 13 & & 2 \\
          &    & 7 & \\
        4 & 20 & & 2 \\
          &    & 9 & \\
        5 & 29 & & 2 \\
          &    & 11 & \\
        6 & 40 & \vdots & 2 \\
          & \vdots  & \vphantom{13}\vdots & \vdots \\
        7 & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        };
        \draw[->] (diff-3-2.east) -- (diff-4-3.170);
        \draw[->] (diff-5-2.east) -- (diff-4-3.190);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @darthbith, your solution looks great. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you like it! If you found it helpful to you, please consider [upvoting or accepting the answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) with the buttons to the left at the top of my answer. Although this is by no means required, its our way of saying "Thanks" here, instead of thanking people with a comment.